# Entity framework clear list of objects from main object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Im using EF 6 to build my app. Ive got entity User and entity BoughtProduct

In User:

```
this.BoughtProducts = new HashSet<BoughtProduct>();
```

Then I do some logic in my app. Sometimes I do sth like this:

```
MyUser.BoughtProducts.Clear();
```

then when I save changes to my context I have following error:

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the
>   foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a
>   relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value.
>   If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship
>   must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another
>   non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In essence this is a db exception. It is complaining that you are violating a foreign key constraint by deleted (MyUser.BoughtProducts.Clear();) the BoughtProducts on the user. Check your db to see how the entities are related. We would need more info to give you a more specific answer

Comment: Some child entity of your Product is not deleted from the database and therefor you can not delete the product because of that relation, please give us more information (datamodel or something like that) so we can see exacly what the problem is

Comment: Do you expect that the records in `BoughtProducts` will be deleted when you call a `Clear` method? As far as I know, the records must be removed manually:

    foreach (var product in user.BoughtProducts)
        context.DeleteObject(product);

    context.SaveChanges();